# Is there some way to ignore line in XML using sonar?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

I need to ignore some lines in xml.

I found //NOSONAR but it's not work in xml.

Comment: In the documentation you can find [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/faq/) FAQ: "//NOSONAR Most language analyzers support the use" so this may be the exception. So maybe you can try to solve this by ignoring based on [blocks](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/).